# How to use QVector as two dimensional array?

Tags: qt, vector, multidimensional-array

How do I declare, initialise, and assign values to a `QVector` as a 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 9):

The same way as a `std::vector`:

```
QVector< QVector< int > > twoDArray;      // Empty.
QVector< QVector< int > > twoDArray( 2 ); // Contains two int arrays.
twoDArray[0].resize(4);
twoDArray[0][2] = 4;  // Assign to the third element of the first array.
...
etc...
```

Comment: It is giving The program has unexpectedly finished when it reaches the assignment statement

Comment: cmannett85 bro please once check it, it leads to unexpected finish

Comment: What is?  I have no idea what you have written.  The above code is not a contiguous block, they're just random examples of use!

Comment: @cmannett85 I think he used your example as it is and got an error because twoDArray doesn't have third element to assign to.

Comment: @Stals Ugh, I thought the ellipsis would have made it obvious that there are steps between.  I'll update it..

Comment: <pre>#include <QtGui/QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<QVector<int> > points;
    qDebug()<<"before ";
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {

            points[i][j] = 56;
            qDebug()<<"pt "<<points[i][j];
        }
    }
    qDebug()<<"after ";
    
    return a.exec();
    } </pre>

Comment: @sai You haven't set the size of the vector, you are creating an empty one and then dialling into it - which will cause a segfault.  `QVector< QVector< int > > points( 10, QVector< int >( 5 ) );` should initialise it properly, please read the docs https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html

Comment: @ cmannett85 thank u bro..now it is working fine. But can we make it dynamic with out set the size initially

Comment: @sai Yes, use `append(..)`, `push_back(..)`, or `operator<<` as normal.

Answer (score 9):

To avoid nested vectors you can map the 2D index space to a 1D index space, at least if you have some (constant) "width" which is the upper bound of your x coordinate:

```
int index(int x, int y) {
    return x + width * y;
}
```

Then use this to index a vector of `width * height` size:

```
QVector<...> vector(width * height);
vector[index(5, 3)] = ...;
```

Comment: Would you recommend this practice? It really seems nice.

Comment: Passing it to a function forces you to also have width and height as arguments?

Comment: At least the width (as this is required in the formula to index it). I recommend passing a `QSize` which encapsulates width and height conveniently. Another option when you have C++11 lambdas available allowing more flexibility is instead of the vector pass a `std::function<Type&(int,int)>` (where `Type` is the type the vector should hold) which is passed the index in the form `x, y` and returns a reference in *any* data structure you like. Then call such a function like this: `doSomething([=](int x, int y){ return myData[x * width + y]; });` Sure it looks complicated but is very flexible.